# Error trying to run bin/cryptogen generate — config=./crypto-config.yaml

Tags: go, blockchain

The error is this "fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error

Runtime stack:

```
runtime.throw(0x1391bff, 0x21)
    /opt/go/go1.9.2.linux.amd64/src/runtime/panic.go:605 +0x95 fp=0x7ff7bfeff360 sp=0x7ff7bfeff340 pc=0x1029845
runtime.goenvs()
    /opt/go/go1.9.2.linux.amd64/src/runtime/os_darwin.go:108 +0x83 fp=0x7ff7bfeff390 sp=0x7ff7bfeff360 pc=0x10270e3
runtime.schedinit()
    /opt/go/go1.9.2.linux.amd64/src/runtime/proc.go:492 +0xa1 fp=0x7ff7bfeff3d0 sp=0x7ff7bfeff390 pc=0x102c221
runtime.rt0_go(0x7ff7bfeff408, 0x4, 0x7ff7bfeff408, 0x0, 0x1000000, 0x4, 0x7ff7bfeff5f0, 0x7ff7bfeff5fe, 0x7ff7bfeff607, 0x7ff7bfeff60b, ...)
    /opt/go/go1.9.2.linux.amd64/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:175 +0x1eb fp=0x7ff7bfeff3d8 sp=0x7ff7bfeff3d0 pc=0x105322b"
```

I am using a mac updated to Ventura 13.4.1

Updated go version and other software I could find but nothing.

I am also a novice. So please take it easy